# Fetching Android contacts in Xamarin Forms application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Part of my Xamarin Forms Android application retrieves the user's contacts from their phone to a List. The method that retrieves the contacts is below.

Up until this point, I had been importing a .vcf file of test contacts into the Android Emulator to test my application. This works correctly and my method returns the list of contacts.

However, when I manually add a contact to the Android Emulator by opening the phone's contacts app and entering a new contact. The method still only returns the .vcf contacts, and does not include the new contact I have just created.

I'm assuming the .vcf contacts are stored in a different way on the phone to manually entered contacts. Am I looking in the wrong place when I create my projection?

```
public class PhoneContacts_Android : IPhoneContacts
{
    private List<Contact> _contacts = new List<Contact>();

    public List<Contact> GetContactsList()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(MainActivity.ThisActivity, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.ContentUri;

            string[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FormattedAddress,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Street,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.City,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Region,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Postcode
            };

            var cursor = MainActivity.ThisActivity.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

            _contacts = new List<Contact>();

            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    var _contact = new Contact();
                    _contact.Address = new Address();

                    _contact.Id = (int) cursor.GetLong(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0]));
                    _contact.DisplayName = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1]));
                    _contact.Address.AddressLine1 = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2]));
                    _contact.Address.AddressLine2 = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[3]));
                    _contact.Address.City = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[4]));
                    _contact.Address.State = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[5]));
                    _contact.Address.ZipCode = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[6]));

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_contact.FirstName) && _contact.DisplayName != null)
                    {
                        string[] words = _contact.DisplayName.Split(' ');
                        _contact.FirstName = words[0];
                        _contact.NickName= words[0];
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_contact.LastName))
                            _contact.LastName = words[1];
                    }

                    _contacts.Add(_contact);

                } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
            }

            return _contacts;
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(MainActivity.ThisActivity, new System.String[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts }, 1);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

My URI was pointed at ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.ContentUri;

If the manually entered contact did not have a postal address it wasn't in the StructuredPostal Data Model.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you can not get contact record that adding manually? You can try the following code, I test it and can get contact record that adding manually.

```
List<Contact> contactList;

void FillContacts()
    {
        //var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

        var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;

        string[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number,
           ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoId
           //ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoThumbnailUri
        };

        // ManagedQuery is deprecated in Honeycomb (3.0, API11)
        //var cursor = activity.ManagedQuery (uri, projection, null, null, null);

        // ContentResolver requires you to close the query yourself
        //var cursor = activity.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        // CursorLoader introduced in Honeycomb (3.0, API11)
        var loader = new CursorLoader(activity, uri, projection, null, null, null);
        var cursor = (ICursor)loader.LoadInBackground();


        contactList = new List<Contact>();

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                contactList.Add(new Contact
                {
                    Id = cursor.GetLong(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0])),
                    DisplayName = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1])),
                    PhoneNumber = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2])),
                    PhotoId = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[3]))
                });
            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }
    }

public class Contact
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhotoId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This does work but the IDE throws a warning stating "CursorLoader is obsolete: deprecated". What should we use in its place?